# Stuck on some fraction

Tags: fractions

In the following manipulation

$$\frac{-(M-\frac{1}{2}\Omega)+\sqrt{(M-\frac{1}{2}\Omega)^2+2\lambda\Omega}}{\Omega} = \frac{-(M-\frac{1}{2}\Omega)^2+(M-\frac{1}{2}\Omega)^2+2\lambda\Omega}{\Omega\left[(M-\frac{1}{2}\Omega)+\sqrt{(M-\frac{1}{2}\Omega)^2+2\lambda\Omega}\right]} \; ,$$

I don't understand why the left fraction is changed to the right fraction.
As I know $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$, but in the picture the $2ab$ term is missing.
I do not understand why that is.

Comment: it is hard to see what is happening on the picture, could you use MathJax to typeset it?

Comment: I have a feeling that there might be a mistake there. I suspect the idea here is to note that
$$
(a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2
$$
And therefore multiplication by $(a-b)$ has to be used. But there's a plus instead of minus ...

Comment: Also, the $\Omega$'s definitely don't cancel out.

Comment: it is $\dfrac {(-A +\sqrt B)}{\Omega}$. Mult num and denom for $(A+B)$ to get : $\dfrac {(-A^2 + B)}{\Omega (A+B)}$.

Comment: Then simplify the num to get $2 \lambda \Omega$ and you can correctly cancel $\Omega$ from both num and denum.

Comment: Yes, Mauro is right. Thank you!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

We want to simplify
$$\frac{-(M-\frac{1}{2}\Omega)+\sqrt{(M-\frac{1}{2}\Omega)^2+2\lambda\Omega}}{\Omega}
= \frac{a+b}{\Omega}$$
And the first thing to notice is that we want to get rid of the square root; in other words we want something like $b^2$ in the numerator. We can expand by $a-b$:
$$
\frac{a+b}{\Omega} = \frac{(a+b)(a-b)}{\Omega (a-b)} = \frac{a^2 -b^2}{\Omega (a-b)}
$$
Plugging in the original values, we obtain
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{-(M-\frac{1}{2}\Omega)+\sqrt{(M-\frac{1}{2}\Omega)^2+2\lambda\Omega}}{\Omega}
= & \frac{(M-\frac{1}{2}\Omega)^2-\left[(M-\frac{1}{2}\Omega)^2+2\lambda\Omega \right]}{\Omega \left( -(M-\frac{1}{2}\Omega) -  \sqrt{(M-\frac{1}{2}\Omega)^2+2\lambda\Omega }\right)} \\
= & \frac{2\lambda}{ (M-\frac{1}{2}\Omega) +  \sqrt{(M-\frac{1}{2}\Omega)^2+2\lambda\Omega }} \\
\end{split}
$$
Whether this is more useful than the first form, depends on the context.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.!!